# Visual Studio: Unit test fails to run with "Error: Could not find property 'MSTestDiscoverer.NeedsLegacyRunner'"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, when I initiate a run of my project's unit tests, the tests fail to start, and the following error appears in the Output window:

`Error: Could not find property 'MSTestDiscoverer.NeedsLegacyRunner'.`

What's causing this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure what was causing this, I was able to fix it by doing a Clean Solution followed by a Rebuild Solution, and then restarting the test run.